# The WSGI module of Nginx is out of date?

Tags: python, nginx

I love python and I want to use python to construct my blog. I have deployed a nginx server and I find [that](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServers) in python wiki:

> In addition to the above, some non-Python-based Web servers support
>   Python-based applications by embedding the Python virtual machine for
>   improved performance:
>
> [Nginx WSGI](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxNgxWSGIModule) support module for Nginx HTTP server

I goto Nginx WSGI wiki page, but find:

> mod_wsgi tested with Nginx 0.8.31 and python-2.6.2

My nginx version is `1.4.4`(deployed one year before)...

I find a update [information page](http://hg.mperillo.ath.cx/nginx/mod_wsgi/file/tip/README) in that wiki page, I click it hopefully:

Browser gives DNS look up error:ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

So, my question is:

1. mod_wsgi is out of date and is not good choice for python server?
2. If I want to use nginx as my http server, what is a better choice?
3. If I don't insist to use nginx, what is my best choice?

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking here. mod_wsgi is for Apache, not nginx. If you want to use nginx, either use the plugin you link to, or preferably use a standalone server like gunicorn and set up nginx as a reverse proxy.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  but I see this on nginx wiki page:`mod_wsgi tested with Nginx 0.8.31 and python-2.6.2`. Maybe it's for apache but it could also be a module in nginx... http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxNgxWSGIModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the preferred way to deploy Python applications with nginx is to use it as a reverse proxy to a standalone Python WSGI server such as gunicorn or uwsgi.

The documentation for both projects includes sample configuration for running with nginx.

Comment: I installed gunicorn but when execute `../bin/gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app` and there is no `[info]` lines output as the quick start claims. But when I run `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000` it output `Hello, World!` as expected. Do you have any idea?